# has_path equivalent in Graph-Tool

Tags: python, graph-tool

Does graph-tool have any equivalent function to NetworkX's has_path? I'd like to return True if there's a valid path between any given nodes.

Comment: can you check the docs?

Comment: I did, but I couldn't find anything unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is trivially achieved by checking if there is a finite distance between two vertices:

```
   has_path = shortest_distance(g, u, v) < g.num_vertices()
```